# Python3 Seaborn PairGrid legend outside subplots

Tags: legend, seaborn, python-3.5

I'm making a large `PairGrid` figure and I am unable to set the legend outside the plots (on the right). `PairGrid` doesn't seem to inherit the `legend_out` option of `FaceGrid`. Here is my attempt so far as you can see the legend overlaps the figure.

```
from random import choice

from numpy import random
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd

def my_kdeplot(dfx, dfy, *args, **kwargs):
    ax = sns.kdeplot(dfx, dfy, alpha=0.7,
                     cmap=sns.light_palette(kwargs['color'], as_cmap=True))

names = [choice('ABCDE') for _ in range(1000)]
df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(names, *[random.random(1000) for _ in range(5)])),
                   columns=['names','A','B','C','D','E'])

g = sns.PairGrid(df, hue='names')

g.map_lower(my_kdeplot)
g.map_upper(plt.scatter, alpha=0.7)
g.map_diag(plt.hist)

g = g.add_legend(fontsize=14)
sns.plt.savefig('fig.png')
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You can adjust the location of your legend using `bbox_to_anchor=(horizontal, vertical)`:

```
g = g.add_legend(fontsize=14, bbox_to_anchor=(1.5,1))
```

You'll need to play with the numbers a little to find the right legend position.